# Mongo DB database for Opencart

Tags: mysql, mongodb, laravel-4, opencart

I am working on a project with MongoDB database but in Opencart database configuration there isn't an option for NoSQL database. I'd like to integrate Opencart into my project. Can someone guide me how to use Opencart using MongoDB? Is it possible that Opencart only uses MySQL database?

Comment: You better ask this question to Opencart directly.

Comment: There are a vast number of differences between Relational and NoSQL databases.

Comment: Relational databases have a common standard -- that they all adhere to but nonetheless they also break it or extend it differently.

Comment: In an app the task of replacing MySQL with Oracle or PostgreSQL may be achievable on the condition that you don't use any of the vendor-specific features (and also use some abstraction layer on top).

Comment: Most noSQL databases on the other hand don't have a common standard which means making one NoSQL db drop-in replaceable by another is hard work. Making the a Relational DB replaceable by a NoSQL db also hard work.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that Open cart only uses MySQL database?

All of the internal queries in Opencart are written in SQL and you can (in theory) use any database which supports it like Oracle, Sybase, Microsoft SQL Server, Access, Ingres, PostgreSQL and of course MySQL.  According to the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-sql):

> Does MongoDB support SQL?
>
> **No**. However, MongoDB does support a rich query language of its own.
>   For examples on using MongoDB’s query language, see MongoDB CRUD
>   Operations

You'll need to choose a database that supports SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer